# How to get random two times

Tags: c#, random

I start learning c#. I try to create strange game but i didn't make random into random that is to say two time random. I tried to do random two times but i don't do. Bug is |x | or | x| don't show, work. (For c#) How can i do this? I want random into random.

```
  static void randomata()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Random r2 = new Random();
        Random r3 = new Random();
        Random r4 = new Random();
        int randomsonuc = r.Next(0, 100);
        int randomsonuc2 = r2.Next(0, 100);
        int randomsonuc3 = r3.Next(0, 100);
        int randomsonuc4 = r4.Next(0, 100);
        if (randomsonuc < 90) // work
        {
            if (randomsonuc2 < 50) // work
            {
                cmake("|XX|", 8, 0);
            }
            else if(randomsonuc2 >= 50) //work
            {
                cmake("|X|", 8, 0);
                cmake("|X|", 8, 1);
            }
        }
       else if (randomsonuc >= 90 && randomsonuc < 95) // work
        {
            if (randomsonuc3 < 50) // doesnt work
            {
                cmake("|X |", 8, 0);
            }
            if (randomsonuc3 >= 50) // work
            {
                cmake("|X|", 8, 0);
                cmake("| |", 8, 1);
            }
        }
        else //(randomsonuc >= 95 && randomsonuc < 100) // work
        {
            if (randomsonuc4 < 50) // doesnt work
            {
                cmake("| X|", 8, 0);
            }
            if (randomsonuc4 >= 50) // work
            {
                cmake("| |", 8, 0);
                cmake("|X|", 8, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "random into random" mean?

Comment: By "random into random", are you wanting to use a random number as a seed to generate another random number? ...Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because [System.Random()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) is seeded with the current time creating lots of instances like this won't do much.

Try creating a single instance of Random and then use that instance wherever you need a random number

```
static void randomata()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomsonuc = r.Next(0, 100);
    int randomsonuc2 = r.Next(0, 100);
    int randomsonuc3 = r.Next(0, 100);
    int randomsonuc4 = r.Next(0, 100);

    ...
}
```